# Можно ли подключится к другому серверу не используя iframe?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность подключится из модуля к другому серверу. 
Написал несколько модулей использующих и `user_id` и обращения к `БД` через `ajax`, но теперь часть базы переносится на другой сервер (для разгрузки того, где все сейчас находится). 
`IP` известен, пробую сейчас переделать вывод через `iframe`, но это на мой взгляд не комильфо.

Если есть более правильный и удобный способ, прошу сообщите.

P.S. Требуется, чтоб все подсчеты, запросы к БД и т.д. происходили на новом серваке, а на этом (старом) отображался результат, но хотелось бы через модуль без использования iframe.

Comment: Нет конечно.... для этого надо маленькое API написать чтобы самописный модуль делал запросы на другой сайт и получал данные оттуда.

Comment: требуется обращение не к сайту, а к php файлам на сервере и к БД.  Получилось, стал передавать данные через `ajax` в одной переменной в виде строки, а не как раньше много переменных. Не `json` и не `jsonp`, а просто строкой.

Comment: > требуется обращение не к сайту а к php файлам на сервере и к БД. Да конечно, я об этом писал )) причём тут сайт ? вам надо делать запросы, например к контролеру своего компонента, если есть, или какой то файл helper.php создать и там получать данные и возвращать в ответ... Если AJAX не объязательный вариант, лучше сделать запросы по CURL. более эффективно будет.

Answer (score 1):

если в настройках перенесенного сервера будет разрешен запрос с удаленных ресурсов:  Access-Control-Allow-Origin
подробнее можно почитать тут:
https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain

Comment: Боюсь, что это не то. Добавил немного пояснения в свой вопрос.